# How to write tab command in c++ to switch input form

Tags: c++, c, forms, input, ditto

I have a database and I want to add that data to a web application using ditto. I copied the data from my domain for me to paste in someone else's domain. With a semicolon separator.

So, I want when the text is pasted, the semicolon changes to the tab command to the next input form. Please help.

Description is in the image in the attachment. Thank you.

[DITTO SCRIPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8xLd.png)

[INPUT FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu0nW.png)

Comment: Looks like a job for `sed` or `tr`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please don't tag unrelated languages (C is *very* different from C++).

Comment: The code in the pictures resembles neither C nor C++. Please also read this snippet from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a vector as a buffer if you're working with ascii characters. just do the same comparisons with a for each loop.

Comment: can ditto use #include <vector>

Comment: @FuadRosadi C++ can - and you listed this as a C++ problem.